# LimitRequestFieldSize does not work

Tags: configuration, http-headers, apache2.2

I'm tryingo to set LimitRequestFieldSize on apache 2.2 configuration, but it does not work.
I can set header which has 16kb of size, LimitRequestFieldSize is set to 150 and everything works, so how can I limit size of Http request header?

I'm running Debian 7